# Why JavaScript objects won't set nested object with a value if they are currently null

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way for an object to know that if a field has a value of `null` to change that to `{}` so I could add data within?

I have a variable named customer of type any
When the server provides the data this customer has a field-object image for his profile picture.

The image has a field called `imageUrl`.

customer: {
    name: 'John',
    image: null,
    ...
}

At first, the image has a value of `null`, and if I want to add `imageUrl` to the customer after I upload the image, I have to do the following:

```
  this.customer.image = {imageUrl: null};
  this.customer.image.imageUrl = imgObj.result.imageUrl;
```

Is there a way to tell the object to do this automatically?

If I do:

```
   this.customer.image.imageUrl = imgObj.result.imageUrl;
```

before setting image to an object with the wanted field I get an error.
Shouldn't the object know that even if image is `null` that if I give `this.customer.image.imageUrl` a value, the only viable option is to set image to an empty `{}`, or is there another reason for this not occurring.

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: JSON doesn't know anything, it's just a textual notation of data. You should probably do this: `this.customer.image = this.customer.image || {};` before assigning the `imageUrl` property so that you don't override `image` property if it exists.

Comment: How are you fetching the json from the server? There are libs out there, that offer a `transform` functionality that you could apply to modify all relevant nulled fields into an object. You cannot avoid having to do the transformation yourself though. In the end, there is no way for TypeScript / JavaScript to know when to transform a nulled value into an object.

Comment: You can do that without any conditionals using lodash [`_.set()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set) function:  `_.set(this.customer, "image.imageUrl", "http://example.org");`. It will create the `image` member if `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks, everyone for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> At first, the image has a value of null, and if I want to add `imageUrl` to the customer after I upload the image, I have to do the following:
>
> ```
> this.customer.image = {imageUrl: null};
> this.customer.image.imageUrl = imgObj.result.imageUrl;
> ```

Or more concisely:

```
this.customer.image = {imageUrl: imgObj.result.imageUrl};
```

There's no *reasonable* way¹ to have `image`'s value automatically updated from `null` to a blank object when you assign to a property on it. That's just not a feature JavaScript/TypeScript have (again, within reason).

It sounds like you're trying to avoid having an `if` in your code, e.g., avoiding:

```
if (!this.customer.image) {
    this.customer.image = {};
}
this.customer.image.imageUrl = imgObj.result.imageUrl;
```

If so, you can avoid it with `||`:

```
this.customer.image = this.customer.image || {};
this.customer.image.imageUrl = imgObj.result.imageUrl;
```

If you want to be really convoluted, you can combine those into a single statement, but it just makes it harder to read, debug, and maintain:

```
(this.customer.image = this.customer.image || {}).imageUrl = imgObj.result.imageUrl;
```

**But** note that assigning `{}` to `this.customer.image` may not work at the TypeScript level if `this.customer.image` is declared to be a type that requires an `imageUrl` property. If that's the case, probably the cleanest approach is an `if` statement:

```
if (this.customer.image) {
    this.customer.image.imageUrl = imgObj.result.imageUrl;
} else {
    this.customer.image = {imageUrl: imgObj.result.imageUrl};
}
```

or `Object.assign`:

```
this.customer.image = Object.assign(
    this.customer.image || {},
    {imageUrl: imgObj.result.imageUrl}
);
```

...since the type of `Object.assign`'s first argument won't have the `imageUrl` requirement.

---

¹ The *unreasonable* way is to make `this.customer` a `Proxy` with special handling of the `image` property: Use the `get` trap and if it's to get the value of `image` and the value of `image` is currently `null`, you could set it to a blank object. (Of course, that would happen if you just did `this.customer.image` without assigning to a property on it, too.) There are **lots** of reasons not to do that, not least complexity.